# php looping through array to create multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to loop though an existing multidimensional array grabbing certain values based on a key.

```
myarray = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count(exampleArray); $i++){
  $myarray = $exampleArray[$i]['wanted_field'];
}
```

This is only giving me one value.

The desired output will have a structure similar to this

```
myarray = ([0]=> 'apple' [1]=> 'orange'
           [0]=> 'plum' [1]=> 'grape' [3]=> 'potato'
          )
```

Comment: one thing;- the desired output you shown will not possible because same indexes are over-written with latest values inside array. So i think you need to reformat your desired output a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Problem:-*** You are over-writing your variable `$myarray` inside  `for()` loop.

***Solution:-*** You have to do it like below:-

```
$myarray = []; // you misses $
for($i = 0; $i < count($exampleArray); $i++){ // you forget $ again
  $myarray[] = $exampleArray[$i]['wanted_field']; //assign values to array
}
```

***Or simply you can use*** [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):-

```
$myarray= array_column($exampleArray, 'wanted_field');
```

***Output of both example:***- https://eval.in/922152

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to extract the values of one column from an array...

```
$myArray = array_column($exampleArray, 'wanted_field');
```

In your case, you were just overwriting the value to the last value in the array.

Comment: I scrolled down to post this as an answer and there it already was.

Comment: I also see it's been added to other answers as well.